# move filename bar.filename, without mentioning filename twice?

Tags: windows, batch, mv

How do I move `filename` to `bar.filename` without mentioning `filename` twice?

In Bash I can just do: `mv {,bar.}filename`. I suppose I could do:

```
set filename="foobar" && mv "%filename%" "bar.%filename%"
```

But that seems overly verbose. Could write a function also, but that seems overkill:

```
@echo off & setlocal ENABLEEXTENSIONS
set str="%1"
call :move %str%

:move
mv/%1/bar.%1
```

Comment: I'm not a `Batch` expert, but something looks amiss with your `set filename=...` line: shouldn't that be `set foobar=...`?

Comment: I don't know such way in DOS or PowerShell and I doubt it exists. I suggest to install Git, as it includes Bash, which is just wonderful